# Trying to do a particular grouping in Django

Tags: python, django

So let's say I have a model, Fruit, with some fields:

```
class Fruit():
color: models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, default='', max_length='250')
sweet: models.BooleanField(default=False)
date_dropped_from_tree: models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
baking: models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want to take my fruit queryset:

```
class FruitViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset= Fruit.objects.all()
serializer_class = FruitSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
self.queryset = self.queryset.filter(sweet=F('sweet'), date_dropped_from_tree=F('date_dropped_from_tree'), baking=F('baking')).values('sweet', 'date_dropped_from_tree', 'baking').annotate(count=Count('sweet', 'date_dropped_from_tree', 'baking'))
return self.queryset
```

I want this to return a queryset that could convert to a list that is something like:

```
[{ sweet: True, date_dropped_from_tree: '10-25-18', baking: False, count=5},
 { sweet: False, date_dropped_from_tree: '10-16-15', baking: True, count=3}, ... 
]
```

Looking as I write it out, I realize my code is a bit off base, but I can't quite conceive of how to return results like I want.  Assistance appreciated.

Comment: What is the result of `return self.queryset` ?

Comment: What do you need the list for? What are you doing with the output?

Comment: I am displaying a table of data with four columns, sweet, date_dropped, baking, and count. The mechanism to convert the query set to a table is in place